# Batch convert .EPS & .AI files to .PSD *With Layers* - Using MAC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, batch-processing, eps, file-conversion

I have a lot of great .eps and .ai files that I'd like to convert to .psd. Does anyone know of a MAC program or website that can handle converting them all while keeping the layers in tact?

I know how to convert them manually in Adobe Illustrator but there are way too many to do them one by one. Any program or website that I've tried isn't able to deliver the separated layers. I need them layers!

I am beyond thankful for anyone that can help me!
Have a great Sunday!

Comment: I downvoted your question as to I dont understand why you want to take several EPS and AI files when you've stated you need the layers and not use them as smart objects in Photoshop? I closed your question as this is a resource gathering question so I don't know if you're expecting someone to write you a script. If you're expecting someone to provide you with free work that isn't in scope and not the purpose of this site.  Stan is also correct in suggesting you can do this with AppleScript and I've done something similar plenty of times. It will take you referencing the AppleScript dictionary.

Comment: Furthermore, requesting to recommend a site isn't in the SE model as the answer would be a link only answer and the site may expire over time.  Answers should be able to live with a question and last over time.  If you will spend some time and read [ask] we may be able to assist.  However, I am unsure what your intention is with this question.  Can this be done? **yes**  Can you script this on your Mac already?  **yes**

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem with my question is. I am asking for advice on how to make an .eps file a .psd file, with the converted file containing layers in photoshop. With a quick google search there are many converters that come up and similar questions on other websites, so this is a relatively in demand topic. I have already tried an applescript action and it did convert the file but did not retain the layers.

Comment: I am not looking for anyone to do the work for me. I was only making suggestions when I suggested a website or program. I just need a way to make this happen and as a batch process. Maybe someone can give me some Applescript editor advice (I would prefer a different method).

Answer (score 1):

You have everything you need, already.

You can use your resident **Macintosh "AppleScript" editor** to create a script that will do what you want.

You can find ready-made scripts on-line for automating just about anything or you can create your own by recording what you do with one file and then running the recorded actions for your other files in batches.

Once will make a believer out of you.

Comment: +1 for suggesting AppleScript.  However, I closed the question as I believe the OP wants someone to provide them with free work.

Comment: @Darth_Vader Thanx for the nod.

Comment: I do not want the work for free. I am looking for advice, links, methods, anything. I can do the work myself, just need feedback.

Comment: I feel like I just got attacked by the real Darth Vader haha

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Stan, I will continue to explore the AppleScript if that is the best way to go.